# how i do infinity parent - child foreach loop in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to do foreach for following json:-

```
const TREE_DATA: FoodNode[] = [
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    children: [
      {name: 'Apple'},
      {name: 'Banana'},
      {name: 'Fruit loops'},
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Vegetables',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Green',
        children: [
          {name: 'Broccoli'},
          {name: 'Brussel sprouts'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'Orange',
        children: [
          {name: 'Pumpkins'},
          {name: 'Carrots'},
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: Eleborate your question a little bit more and also post what you've tried so far.

Comment: I am  tried this one method to get data of an array                                                                        
   TREE_DATA.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element)
      element.children.forEach(seconddata=>{
        console.log(seconddata)
      })
    });

Comment: I'm guessing you'd like to run through all the nodes of your tree. In which order do you want to display the data ? (Per depth level, per branch...)

Comment: I just want to push index in this array and want to make a new  array

Comment: In which order do you want to display the data ?  ->>>(Per depth level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use a recursive function

```
  showData(element,level,parent)
  {
    element.forEach(x=>
    {
      x.level=level
      x.parent=parent
      console.log(x.name,x.level,x.parent);
      if (x.children)
          this.showData(x.children,x.level+1,x.name)
    })
  }
```

You call as

```
  this.showData(TREE_DATA,0,null)
```

See that we add two new properties to the data "level", and "parent" that we can use